# Why does this array-reshaping routine work outside of a function but not inside of a function?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, reshape, array-broadcasting

I am trying to convert a list into a numpy array with a specified number of columns. I can get the code to work outside the function as follows:

```
import numpy as np

ls = np.linspace(1,100,100) # Data Sample
ls = np.array(ls) # list --> array

# resize | outside function
ls.resize(ls.shape[0]//2,2)
print(ls)

>> [[   1.    2.]
    [   3.    4.]
           .
           .
           .
    [  97.   98.]
    [  99.  100.]]
```

I do not understand my error when trying to throw the routine in a function. My attempt is as follows:

```
# resize | inside function
def shapeshift(mylist, num_col):
    num_col = int(num_col)
    return mylist.resize(mylist.shape[0]//num_col,num_col)

ls = shapeshift(ls,2)
print(ls)

>> None
```

I want to define the original function in this way because I want another function, consisting of the same inputs and a third input to loop over rows when extracting values, to call this original function for each loop over rows.

Comment: I suspect that `resize` works in-place and returns `None`. Try returning `mylist` itself one line later.

Comment: Returning `mylist` one line later makes no difference in the function output. If the `resize` works in-place, is there a more efficient and convenient method of achieving this without for loops? Ultimately, I'd like to define another function with the same inputs and a third input, so that I can call the function above and loop over each row.

Comment: Apparently the function form (i.e. `np.resize(a, new_shp)` as opposed to the method form `a.resize(new_shp)`) does not work in-place and creates a new array. So you could try using that instead.

Comment: I tried that method but it only returns the first `new_shp` elements. If `new_shp=2`, then it returns `[1,2]`. I suppose I could make the function argument a list of even values from `2` to `100` for this sample case, but I am still hopeful that there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: You can use a tuple for `new_shp`; like `np.reshape(a, (m, n))`. In your example `m=50, n=2`.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. I can mark it correct if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [402]: ls = np.linspace(1,100,10)
In [403]: ls
Out[403]: array([   1.,   12.,   23.,   34.,   45.,   56.,   67.,   78.,   89.,  100.])
In [404]: ls.shape
Out[404]: (10,)
```

No need to wrap again in `array`; it already is one:

```
In [405]: np.array(ls)
Out[405]: array([   1.,   12.,   23.,   34.,   45.,   56.,   67.,   78.,   89.,  100.])
```

`resize` operates in-place.  It returns nothing (or None)

```
In [406]: ls.resize(ls.shape[0]//2,2)
In [407]: ls
Out[407]: 
array([[   1.,   12.],
       [  23.,   34.],
       [  45.,   56.],
       [  67.,   78.],
       [  89.,  100.]])
In [408]: ls.shape
Out[408]: (5, 2)
```

With this `resize` you aren't changing the number of elements, so `reshape` would work just as well.

```
In [409]: ls = np.linspace(1,100,10)
In [410]: ls.reshape(-1,2)
Out[410]: 
array([[   1.,   12.],
       [  23.,   34.],
       [  45.,   56.],
       [  67.,   78.],
       [  89.,  100.]])
```

`reshape` in either method or function form returns a value, leaving `ls` unchanged.  The `-1` is a handy short hand, avoiding the `//` division.

This is the inplace version of reshape:

```
In [415]: ls.shape=(-1,2)
```

`reshape` requires the same total number of elements.  `resize` allows you to change the number of elements, truncating or repeating values if needed.  We use `reshape` much more often then `resize`.  `repeat` and `tile` are also more common than `resize`.

Comment: This example served as a great tutorial. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `.resize` method works in-place and returns `None`. It also refuses to work at all if there are other names referencing the same array. You can use the function form, which creates a new array and is not as capricious:

```
def shapeshift(mylist, num_col):
    num_col = int(num_col)
    return np.resize(mylist, (mylist.size//num_col,num_col))
```